# Migrate files from OS 9 software and hardware to OS X

Tags: macos, network, file-sharing

I'm trying to migrate some files from my old PowerComputing PPC computer(SCSI) that ran OS 9.0.4 to my current MacBook Pro running OS X (default 10.9.4 but 10.6.8 avail via external disk). I've gotten most of the way there. Short version of my quest below in case it helps others, but have been hit by what appears to be a TCP/network configuration issue between the two networks.

Tried the obvious but they don't have compatible ports so no USB(new system but not old - thumb drive, external drive), no Firewire (new system but not old - External drive, target mode), SCSI(on old system but not new).

I found a path that has high potential though, Ethernet. I have an old Farallon adapter on the PPC system that takes the AAUI port and converts it to 10-base-T.

- Had issues with the TCP/IP config on the old system. But went to the TCP/IP control panel to update connection to use DHCP instead of the old static values I had.
- Hooked them both up to the same router and got the IP addresses. Tuned on file sharing via the Control Panel on OS9( and made sure I had a user with access and a password I knew)
- Pinged to make sure there was connectivity
- Tried to connect from OSX 10.9 to OS9 but failed with message about software being incompatible; Did some digging, and it turns out that Apple had removed some needed components.
- I had an external drive that still had 10.6.8 so I tried that. Yeah - it connected 
  :-) (Use AFP - afp:// 192.168.0.7 in my case)
- Started to copy some files. It got a little ways in and died and then disconnected the remote OS9 system.
  it said that the data could not be read or written and gave error code - 36
- If I go back and try it in smaller chances from where it died the copies work.
- During my earlier searching I do remember seeing a post (which I can't find again) that talked about modifying some of the block sizes in the TCP config. Does anyone have any ideas of what they might be?

Thanks for any clues/pointers

Update- I'm getting closer. While it still does fail. I can do it smaller chunks when I hit an error. Since these are OLD SCSI drives the file size/count isn't as large as it would be on a new drive. So while not quick its not as bad as it could have been. I'm going to make one friend very happy. I found an archive of the very first website I had made for her years ago. Some drives are having issues are are saying I need to update the Drivers on it. Going to try everything else I can before I take what might be an irreversible action.

Comment: Possible alternative: pull the HDD out of the old machine and use something like [this](http://kingwin.com/products/cate/accessories/adapters/usi_2535.php). Not sure what interface the internal drive on the OS 9 machine is; if it's IDE or ATA, that would work fine.

Comment: I may do that as a last resort, but its multiple drives. One internal on the computer and a bunch externals that will be a pain to open just to see what lower level connector may be used. I don't want to disable the drive just to find out I can't connect to it. Plus it looks like some have issues and I may have to update the drivers on them

Answer (score 1):

ftp.  osx hosts it, os9 goes in as client.

ever faithful, ever sturdy.